# Admob in xml not showing in Linear

Tags: android, xml, layout, admob

I am implementing admob on my app it appears when the parent is in relative layout but I must not use the *alignparentbottom* so I am changing it to linear but it doesn't show when I change it to linear..

any tips? help?

here it is in xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/banner_holder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/offline_banner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@color/black"
            android:src="@drawable/offline_banner" />

        <com.google.ads.AdView
            xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/unit_id"
            ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
 <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I want the admob to be at the bottom part of the screen without using the *alignparentbottom* of relative layout

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: the admob it is not showing when parent is in LinearLayout

Comment: Can you post the layout in which it doesn't work?

Comment: put layout so so user can understand..

Comment: i think it is already posted. O_O that is the xml file

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you're avoiding alignParentBottom but the layout below worked for me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

   <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" /> 
   <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/banner_holder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:weight="1" >

            <!-- Everything in here will hug the bottom -->

   </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: because it makes the activity go down.. which is i am avoiding. i will try this thanks

Comment: it still dont show the admob :( the Frame is eating all the space

Comment: Okay so you essentially want to framelayout to scroll your content and for the admob layout area to remain at the bottom no matter how much room the framelayout takes up?

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this 
1. download latest google-play-services,jar
2. add jar to project build path

**main.xml**
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/lnrMain">

</LinearLayout>

public class MyActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    LinearLayout lnrMain;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        lnrMain = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lnrMain);

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                AdView adView = new AdView(MyActivity.this);
                adView.setAdUnitId("0445b7141d9d4e1b");
                adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
                AdRequest.Builder builder = new AdRequest.Builder();
                builder.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR);
                adView.loadAd(builder.build());
                lnrMain.addView(adView);
            }
        });

    }
}

**AndroidManifest.xml**
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.Demo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name="MyActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="ADMOB_ALLOW_LOCATION_FOR_ADS"
            android:value="true" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="4030500" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: i need to have a space for offline banner. not only the admob itself :(